# Err_too_many_redirects cakephp

Tags: php, apache, cakephp

Tengo un proyecto creado en cakephp ejecutado en un xampp ya configure la base de datos y cambie la carpeta tmp a la que trae cakephp pero al ejecutar el proyecto, el navegador me da este error:
"Err_too_many_redirects"

todas las peticiones me devuelven un 403, tambien hice un trace del error y el log me muestra lo siguiente:

```
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\ubora\lib\Cake\Error\ErrorHandler.php(213): ErrorHandler::handleFatalError(64, ‘‘continue’ not …’, ‘C:\xampp\htdocs…’, 1852)
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\ubora\lib\Cake\Core\App.php(970): ErrorHandler::handleError(64, ‘‘continue’ not …’, ‘C:\xampp\htdocs…’, 1852, Array)
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\ubora\lib\Cake\Core\App.php(943): App::_checkFatalError()
#3 [internal function]: App::shutdown()
#4 {main}
```

me falta algo de configuración la verdad soy nuevo con este framework

Answer (score 0):

Lo que debes hacer si no está hecho ya es habilitar el módulo "rewrite" de apache, y habilitar el "rewrite" en tu carpeta del sitio, algo cómo esto

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride all
    Require all denied
</Directory>
```

Reinicias el servicio y debería ser todo.

Comment: Hice una prueba descargandome cakephp 3 y me funciona perfecto con mi configuración.
He seguido investigando y parece que es por el componente AuthComponet que retorna no autorizado y tiene configurado redireccionar al index
Se te ocurre alguna cosa?
gracias de antemano